# Ubercart import catalog

Tags: 7, importing-exporting

I’m using drupal 7 with [Ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart) version 7.x-3.8

I would like to now if there is a way to mass import different taxonomy vocabulary from a csv file.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the module that you need to import taxonomy from csv https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv